# Spectral Clustering using Negative Euclidean Distances

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning, spectral-analysis

In most spectral clustering papers I've seen (von Luxburg's tutorial, Michael Jordan's NIPS paper, and some papers that predate those), they like using the affinity matrix generated by the Gaussian kernel.

It seems to me simpler to look at the spectrum of the negative distance matrix (or negative square-of-distance matrix). Note that in this case I want the spectrum of that matrix, not its derived Laplacian.

I looked around and can't find people who do what I describe.

Why not? It seems simple enough.

Experimentally, the method works fine on toy data sets, and there are theoretical reasons I prefer the negative distance matrix.

(SKLearn's page on spectral clustering warns me to not have negative entries in a similarity matrix. Experimentally, the "bad consequences" of having negative entries do not apply here.)